# Problem with For in a dictionary in a list [Python]

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

Im a beginner on Python, got an exercise on a youtube class that im having problem with, here is the code:

```
from datetime import date
list = []
data = {}
while True:
    data['name'] = input('Name: ').title().strip()
    data['birth'] = int(input('Year of birth [XXXX]: '))
    data['age'] = date.today().year - data['birth']
    data['ctps'] = int(input('Num. CPTS (if none enter 0): '))
    if data['ctps'] != 0:
        data['hiredate'] = int(input('Hired on: '))
        data['income'] = float(input('What`s your income: $'))
        data['retirement'] = (data['hiredate'] + 35) - data['birth']
    list.append(data.copy())
    data.clear()
    p = input('Want to finish? [Y/N] ').upper().strip()
    if p not in 'NY':
        p = input('Invalid option. Want to finish? [Y/N]')
    if p == 'Y':
        break
print('-'*30)
for i in list:
    print(f'Name is {data["name"]}')
```

and i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\*****\******\*****\*****\*****.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(f'Name is {data["name"]}')
KeyError: 'name'
```

I intent to run a for command through that list, printing each name added to the dictionary in that list. I know there are other ways of solving this (i usually use 'for i in range(0, len(list))'), but i wish to solve it this way, if possible.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You unconditionally call `data.clear()` and then attempt of access a entry in `data`. Do you mean to index `i` instead, as in `i["name"]`? Also note that it is generally a bad practice to shadow builtins such as [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list), especially in the global scope.

Comment: @Brian has the right answer.  Your last line should be `print(f'Name is {i["name"]}')`

Comment: Your code puts a whole lot of stuff in `data` and then correctly makes a copy of it before appending the copy to `list` (as another comment says, a bad name, but that is not the problem). Then your code iterates through `list` using `i` to refer to each element of the list. But your `print()` call refers to `data["name"]` and `data` was cleared. What I think you meant is `print(f'Name is {i["name"]}')`.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Worked like a charm, thank you for your quick and clear answers. I think i`m not allowed to upvote answers yet